# Solr error on full-import

Tags: solr, error-handling

Im trying to get a test running with solr, a "full-import" from Ms Sql server.

when calling:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

I receive an http 404 error

Problem accessing /solr/dataimport. Reason: 
    Not Found

This dosent help me much. Is there a way to debug or a way to receive more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the dataimport handler configured in your solrconfig. Check the documentation, is just matter of copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting solr.

You could also try:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true
```

EDIT:

Though my guess is that your data-config, solrconfig, and solr xml files are just not configured correctly. I would look into these files as well. Hope that helps.